# How to refine the debugging?

Tags: erlang

Crash report (SASL) gives more or less where and why a bug happens.
But is it possible to refine this (the function, the line de code, etc) ?

Comment: Would be nice if crash reports gave where and why a bug happens. Unfortunately they give you where and why it crashed, and sometimes that has nothing to do where and why the bug happens :(

Comment: Could provide us with a sample crash report?

Comment: How to debug a portion of code where we suspect there is a problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can reproduce the fault, the best way to get more information is to put a dbg trace on sections in question and review that output.

```
dbg:tracer(),dbg:p(all,c),dbg:tpl(Mod,Func,x).
```

This usually does the trick for me. Replace Mod and Func with whatever module and function you want to debug.

If you are looking for more detailed post-mortem logging then sasl and the error_logger are your friends. There are of course times when SASL does not give you enough info, if this happens a lot in your system you probably should either learn to understand the SASL output better or write your own log handler. It is quite easy to plug-in your own error handler into SASL and output things as you want.

You will however never get line number as that information is destroyed at compilation time and there is no way for the VM to know which line crashed. It does however know which function and possibly with which arguments, given this it is usually possible to find out where things went wrong. Unless you write very long functions, which IMO is bad code smell and a sign that you should refactor your code to smaller functions.

Comment: you could, but usually you would enter it into the erlang shell. Note that these functions are for debugging only, not for logging. they break last call optimizations of your code so if left on for too long might cause the VM to run out of memory.

Comment: Just realized, you cannot put this in the actual function that you are debugging. It needs to be executing before running the code so if you want to put it in your code, do it at application startup or somewhere like that. Issuing it in the erlang shell is the prefered method though and should work unless you are debugging startup behaviour.

Comment: I tried but as I start my application from an IDE with application:start(myAppli) I don't know where the result is visible (in the SASL log ?)

Comment: They are outputted in stdio, don't know how that will work with Eclipse (which I assume that you are using?). My guess is that vlad probably had to do some funky stuff with the io of an erlang node to get it integrated into Eclipse. You will have to check the documentation of your IDE for how to debug in it as I know little about how Eclipse (or any other IDE) works.

Comment: Go for redbug instead if you can. If you are not careful with dbg's tracers you can hose the system completely - which is bad if it is production.

Comment: With great power comes great responsibility :) personally I think the output of redbug is too verbose, but that's just my opinion

Answer (score 2):

In general, no. The erlang .beam files does not contain the line numbers from the original code, so it is hard to know at what line the problem occurred. I do have a number of macros I use in my project, included as `"log.hrl"`:

```
-define(INFO(T), error_logger:info_report(T)).
-define(WARN(T), error_logger:warning_report(
    [process_info(self(), current_function), {line, ?LINE} | T])).
-define(ERR(T), error_logger:error_report(
    [process_info(self(), current_function), {line, ?LINE} | T])).

-define(DEBUG(Format, Args), io:format("D(~p:~p:~p) : "++Format++"~n",
                                   [self(),?MODULE,?LINE]++Args)).
-define(DEBUGP(Args), io:format("D(~p:~p:~p) : ~p~n",
                                   [self(),?MODULE,?LINE, Args])).
```

and this does give you some log lines in the program to hunt for. For debugging I often also use the *redbug* tool from the *eper* suite:

https://github.com/massemanet/eper

It allows you to trace in realtime whenever a call happens:

```
 Eshell V5.8.3  (abort with ^G)
 1> redbug:start("erlang:now() -> stack;return", [{time, 60*1000}]).
 ok
 2> erlang:now().
 {1297,183814,756227}

 17:50:14 <{erlang,apply,2}> {erlang,now,[]}
   shell:eval_loop/3 
   shell:eval_exprs/7 
   shell:exprs/7 

 17:50:14 <{erlang,apply,2}> {erlang,now,0} -> {1297,183814,756227}
 3>
```

I hope this helps.